# Nesting for loops in if statements in ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I need to loop through a variable list and embed the `<debug nested for loop>` code in a jinja2 template.

Here is what the playbook looks like

```
 vars:
  env:
  - dev
  - prod
  - staging

 tasks:
 - name: set variable
   set_fact:
   denv: 'dev'

 - name: debug for loop
   debug: msg='{% for i in env %} {{i}} {% endfor %}'

 - name: debug nested for loop
   debug: msg='{% if denv =='{% for i in env %} {{i}} {% endfor %}' %} yay {% else %} nay {% endif %}'
```

The goal is to loop through the `env` list and if the values match `denv` print `yay` else print `nay`

Any idea on how to better write this? The way it is currently written is triggering errors.

Comment: Just like you would do with any other language with `if` and `for`. Looks like a problem for first month of the most basic programming course for children. The example you posted is even painful to look at.

Comment: If you feel deeply offended by a remark that some code which you posted (containing structure `if a=(for i in ...) then .. else ...`) defies basic programming knowledge, that's your personal problem. If you'd write it according to the common sense `for i in ...; if a=f(i)... then ... else ...`, you'd have a solution for your programming "problem", although without having the opportunity to show your big mouth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need a nested loop. What you want is to check for a value within a list right? Try using the when keyword. That way your debug message will only say Yay when it finds the right value.

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    envs:
    - dev
    - prod
    - staging

  tasks:
    - name: set variable
      set_fact:
        denv: 'dev'
    - name: find dev
      debug: msg="Yay it's {{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ envs }}"
      when: item == denv
```

Comment: The script needs to go in a jinja2 formatted template which is why I'm using the raw statements.

Comment: In a jinja2 template, use the same logic: loop over `envs` and then use the condition `{% for e in envs %}{% if denv == e %} Yay it's {{ e }} {% else %} Nay it's not {{ e }} {% endif %}{% endfor %}`